# ACOSJ gives incorrect result from apdu.getOffsetCData

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

I'm working with the u2f-ledger-fido reference code and when I load it into an ACOSJ, contactless works fine, but in contact mode I always get 7 back from `getOffsetCData`, even if I send a raw APDU of 4 bytes total length.

The problem is that when I am expecting to load the attestation certificate in contact mode I'm losing two bytes from the beginning because the offset is incorrect.

I've tried with `gp` and with `pyApduTool` and this is happening in each case.

Can anybody else with an ACOSJ device confirm that in contact mode `apdu.getOffsetCData` always returns 7?

Comment: Thanks Maarten. Yes a representative has confirmed that getOffsetCData is not returning the correct value and to continue with a manual workaround. It's not such a big problem, though it is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This does feel like an implementation bug to me. For a 4 byte ISO Case 1 command the correct result should be 5 (even if there is no CDATA present) as an ISO Case 1 APDU cannot be extended length.

The API documentation of `getOffsetCData` is badly written and doesn't clearly specify the result, especially for Case 1 & 2, but just returning 7 - assuming extended length - cannot be right.

[The comment by Billy in the comments confirmed my suspicion that this is a bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94535/billy-back-bedroom):

> ... a representative has confirmed that `getOffsetCData` is not returning the correct value and to continue with a manual workaround ...

Comment: I thought of closing the question, but I've posted an answer instead so that the issue can be found by other devs walking into it.

Comment: For those interesting in a workaround, there is this gist https://gist.github.com/benbenbenbenbenben/cfe31b2f6abb38bdf503b4679d783d9a